# Transaction pending

Tags: transactions

I received the bitcoin yesterday, and I was told " it may take up to 30 minutes before your bitcoin is available to trade". But until today they are still not available. I'd like to know the reason and how soon they are going to be available. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The most common holdup in this kind of situation is that the Bitcoins are not confirmed.

Depending on the circumstances this may resolve itself in five minutes, take longer than that, or never resolve itself without human intervention.